# Accessibility-friendly way to hide anchor outlines in IE and Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, focus, accessibility

First of all, *I'm aware* that [removing outlines hampers keyboard navigation](http://outlinenone.com/).

The way Google Chrome (for example) solves this is by only showing outlines *when the user uses the keyboard*. Internet Explorer and Firefox, however, seem to show them even when I click with the mouse - and I don't like this.

So what I'd want is a way to make IE (down to version 7 if possible) and/or Firefox not show these outlines when I click (on an anchor, image inside an anchor, etc), but still show them when I use the keyboard, like the way Google Chrome behaves.

It is very ideal if this solution works with only CSS (even if using non-standard fixes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the problem nicely for IE 8 and Firefox.

```
a:hover, a:active { outline: none; }
```

However there is something that took me forever to figure out: it won't work if the targets of the links do not point anywhere. This means that it won't work for something like `<a href="#">`.

[Source](http://people.opera.com/patrickl/experiments/keyboard/test#outline-suppressed-on-hover-and-active).